# Why does this jQuery image picker work in FireFox but not IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Using the jQuery Image Picker plugin from http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ (which works in IE), placed it on my own site with the following HTML:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1" data-img-src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></option>
    <option value="2" data-img-src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></option>
    <option value="3" data-img-src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></option>
</select>
```

and the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').imagepicker();
});
```

Appears to work fine in FireFox, but not IE. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5bVsV/

Comment: What version of IE? I tried with IE9 on fiddle and gave error "access denied", but only with 1.10.1 jQuery, jQuery 1.6.4 with the standard works.

Comment: IE 11... well that's interesting.

Comment: In IE11 I must set jQuery 1.9.1, 1.10 break the plugin (!!)

Comment: Tried IE11 too. JSFiddle does not work, website does. I don't have a solution but I admire the problem. ;)

Comment: There's code in jQuery 1.10.1 that doesn't work in IE; it's all changed in version 1.10.2.  If you use the "1.10.x" "edge" setting, it works in IE9. (Line 1513 in 1.10.1 is trying to access something that IE doesn't think it should.)

Comment: I tried with IE9 with jQuery 1.10.2 and it worked normally only gets discs lists. I think the problem is JSFiddle. Or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is because of a jQuery 1.10.1 bug on `attachEvent`:

> The javascript method attachEvent was replaced with the method
>   addEventListener in IE11.  JQuery 1.10.1 still uses this method in
>   case of IE > 8. This will cause javascript compilation errors.  JQuery
>   1.10.2 seems to have solved this problem.

Ref: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14386

Fiddle with 1.10.2: http://jsfiddle.net/5bVsV/2/

Comment: I think also bug [13980](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980) whose description quotes the exact line of code that causes the exception.